# Symfony - How to add form fields that are not embeeded in the underlying object

Tags: php, forms, validation, symfony

I'm new with Symfony and I'm trying to understand how to make a good form for a login. 
As far as I'm now, I understood that when i'm calling the "isValid()" method, I'm checking if the form submitted data is consistent with the properties of the underlying object (i.e. login object).

Now, this implies an absolute equality between form field and object properties, which is the core of my problem:

what if I want to use fields that not match with any of the login object properties?
E.g. "remember my login" checkbox, which automates login for already logged user.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in your form builder you can add a property **mapped => false** means it’s not validated against the model and therefore no need to implement separate get/set() methods

here is an example:

```
$builder
->add("firstName", "text")
->add("lastName", "text")
->add("emailAddress", "email")
->add("t_and_c", "checkbox", array(
    "mapped" => false,
    "constraints" => new True(array(
        "message" => "Please accept the Terms and conditions in order to register")
    ),
)
```

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for this in the official DOC pdf but i found nothing. Can you suggest me some resource for symfony forms? thx

Comment: No worries :) 
I have found this link that explain how is the architecture behind symfony2 forms. Hope is helpful to you:

http://webmozarts.com/2012/03/06/symfony2-form-architecture/